# Package Enumitem: Yields Error:?

Tags: enumitem

I want to make a list in LaTeX. Here is a minimal working example of the problem:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report} 
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, `top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\begin{document}

\setlist[description] {font=\textendash\enskip\scshape\bfseries} 

\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*)}]  
\litem{$S$ is comprehensive} First term description.  
\litem{Term two} Second term description. 
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

I got the error in console:

> l.4 \usepackage
>                  {enumitem}
>   ?

So I tried to install enumitem package from [Here](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en), but I still get the same error.

I also tried running `enumitem.sty` from my newly installed `enumitem` package, and got the error:

> l.12 \NeedsTeXFormat
>                       {LaTeX2e}
>   ?

Here is the specific distro: (It's MikTeX)[image]

Comment: You will have to provide much more information. You can find out which tex system you use by looking in the log-file. It also contains exact error messages.

Comment: Let me know if this is sufficient info. I am happy to add more. I just need to know what to add.

Comment: Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with `documentclass ...` and ending with `\end{document}` which reproduce your problem,

Comment: If you have miktex don't install package manually, use the miktex console. And don't use the `pdftex` profile for typesetting, you need pdflatex (with la in the middle).

Comment: Added a MWE to the post

Comment: What is that  `  doing in the `geometry` line? (hmm, that is a hard char to get the site to show). Also what is `\litem`?

Comment: `*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
`

Comment: @daleif Unrelated, but how do you write the backtick without making the next word in this formatting?

Comment: @Jan currently no, did try doubles space single space doubles, did not seem to work. It is probably in the formatting guide somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report} 
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\begin{document}

\setlist[description] {font=\textendash\enskip\scshape\bfseries} 

\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*)}]  
\item{$S$ is comprehensive} First term description.  
\item{Term two} Second term description. 
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: So I just needed `item`, and not `litem`?

Comment: @EverythingEnds I also deleted the backtick before `top`.